# Line chart with Proper Dates - Plotly R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, lubridate

```
readdata <- read.csv(file="rawdata.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
readdata
        Month Percentage
1  01 09 2015       0.13
2  01 10 2015       0.14
3  01 11 2015       0.14
4  01 12 2015       0.13
5  01 01 2016       0.13
6  01 02 2016       0.13
7  01 03 2016       0.13
8  01 04 2016       0.14
9  01 05 2016       0.14
10 01 06 2016       0.14
11 01 07 2016       0.14
12 01 08 2016       0.15
13 01 09 2016       0.16
```

I wish to plot a simple line chart with all dates(Months) formatted as "mmm-yy" and the value as percentage.

My take

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
finaldata <- dmy(readdata$Month)
    plot_ly(x=finaldata, y=Percentage, name ="Test", mode = "lines+markers", text = paste(Percentage, "%", sep = ""), hoverinfo = "text")
```

This gets produces
[image]
However, each months cannot be seen? I want x-axis as Sep-15, Oct-15, Nov-15, Dec-15...and so.

If I add `%>% layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))`. The x-axis gets plotted as

[image]
but as I said I wish to have them in "mmm-yy" format.

P.S: I want a line chart which I plan to use in Shiny dashboard. I can change the format of `rawdata.csv` if required.

Comment: https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickmode

Comment: Actually, using the options `tickmode="array", tickvals=finaldata, ticktext=format(finaldata, "%b-%Y")` gives pretty much the same result as above.

Comment: It says, "Based on info supplied, a 'scatter' trace seems appropriate." & further "scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'tickmode"

Answer (score 0):

The missing "Oct 2015" appears when you zoom in. It's not visible in the original zoom level because plotly's designers pick a default level of visual clutter or "busy-ness". The designer's decisions tend to be pretty good. And even if you disagree, working against the software defaults can make future development harder than it needs to be, or make your code more prone to breaking when plotly update their APIs.

If you *really* want every month on the outermost zoom level, you can do this:

```
dates_with_months <- format(finaldata,"%Y-%m")
plot_ly(x=dates_with_months, 
        y=Percentage, name ="Test", 
        mode = "lines+markers", 
        text = paste(Percentage, "%", sep = ""), hoverinfo = "text")
```

Note that this only works with equally-spaced data.

Comment: Upon running, it says "Based on info supplied, a 'bar' trace seems appropriate" and a bar chart is produced. Further the x axis gets arrange in ascending order...and starts with Apr, then Aug, Dec and so on.

Comment: Re: ordering - I've edited the dates_with_months definition so an ordered sort gives the right result.

Comment: @Jason.`dates_with_months <- format(finaldata,"%Y-%m")` results in plot with dates as numbers e.g. 2017-06. Is there a way to have the month spelled out like 2017-May

Comment: From the `R` prompt, `help(format.POSIXct)` should help you pick a suitable display format. `%b` is likely what you want, but do check out the other options.

Comment: Note that spelling out the months runs a risk that the date will be treated like a string, and get sorted alphabetically, e.g. ordered 2017-Apr, 2017-Aug, 2017-Dec, etc. Using numbers in the YYYY-mm format means that even an alphabetical sort gives the desired result.